# Calling .delete deletes all sibling records in the same @OneToMany association

Tags: jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0, one-to-many, ebean

I have the following mapping:

**Parameter:**

```
public class Parameter extends Model {

    @Id
    public long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("parameter DESC")
    public List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();

}
```

**Attribute:**

```
public class Attribute extends Model {

    @Id
    public long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    public Parameter parameter;

}
```

And I have a delete() method in a controller:

```
public Result deleteAttribute(attributeId) {
    Attribute a = Attribute.find.byId(attributeId);
    if (a == null) {
        return notFound();
    }
    a.delete();
    return ok();
}
```

when calling this method, everything works, the attribute record is deleted. However, **all other records that belong to the same parameter are also deleted**.

What is the issue with my mapping here? Shouldn't the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` mean that deleting the owning `Parameter`deletes the attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior when you use `CascadeType.ALL` or `CascadeType.REMOVE`. As described in *JPA 2.0 Specification (JSR-317)*, chapter *3.2.3 Removal*:

> If `X` is a managed entity, the remove operation causes it to become
>   removed. The remove operation is cascaded to entities referenced by `X`,
>   if the relationships from `X` to these other entities is annotated with
>   the `cascade=REMOVE` or `cascade=ALL` annotation element value.

In your case `X` is represented by `a` so the `EntityManager.remove` operation causes to remove `a` along with the referenced Parameter instances. Moreover if any of the referenced Parameter instances is removed then cascading operation implicitly remove the corresponding attributes from its list.

Side note: lack of `mappedBy` in the bidirectional relationship does not specify the owner (the owning side of the relationship that contains FK) and leads to additional join table consisting of two foreign keys which is considered as JPA pitfall.

I would propose to modify the relationship a little, for example:

```
// Parameter
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parameter", cascade = ALL) // the non-owning
@OrderBy("parameter DESC")
public List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();

// Attribute
@ManyToOne(cascade = { DETACH, MERGE, PERSIST, REFRESH }) // the owning
@JsonIgnore
public Parameter parameter;
```

Going this way only `a` and its referenced Parameter instances will be deleted.